# Ansi colours on Windows 10, sort of not working

Tags: windows, go, terminal

Console with colours is fairly new and exciting for Windows :-)

`I wrote some programs that printed using the ansi colour escapes and all was good` ...

... then suddenly it stopped working. Or at least stopped on my laptop, Windows 10.0.14393

The app that fails on my machine does so in a console that a nodejs app has displayed colour in, the same binary runs with the correct colour on another laptop.

golang

    `fmt.Println("\033[31mSome Text\033[0m")`

[image: It looks like this]

*left-top, console node output, left-bottom, my app failing, right vscode*

*httpDump.exe is the name of this demo (in case it was confusing)*

It does display correctly in the vscode integrated terminal window.

I've tried deleting the `HKLM\Console` registry entry and restarting (several times). I deleted the short-cut that may have settings in it. I've tried running as another user on this machine (does not work)

I'd welcome any hints.

Comment: If you need it just for yourself, install ConEmu (https://conemu.github.io/) terminal emulator that understands ANSI escape sequences. It'll work on any Windows version where ConEmu works.

Comment: I have used this and other similar terminals but stopped once windows 10 nativly supported keyboard copy/paste and ANSI control codes (or at least some of the colours). I may have a copy to try and see if it leads anywhere. Thanks Paul.

Comment: see also [github.com/danielchatfield/go-chalk](https://github.com/danielchatfield/go-chalk)

Comment: @Plato, this library *very specifically* states _noop on Windows_ . On non-Windows builds it does exactly what I do. As I've said my program used to work (I've not changed it) but some other local  system change has caused it to no longer work. Thanks for your idea though.

Answer (score 8):

You have to enable virtual terminal processing on Windows since that update.

I usually add a file `init_windows.go` which sets this in windows but is also compatible with other OS:

```
// +build windows

package main

import (
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

func init() {
    stdout := windows.Handle(os.Stdout.Fd())
    var originalMode uint32

    windows.GetConsoleMode(stdout, &originalMode)
    windows.SetConsoleMode(stdout, originalMode|windows.ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING)
}
```

as copied from: https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus/issues/172#issuecomment-353724264

Comment: It worked for me. For some reason I need to put this code in my application's main.go so that the terminal is colored. On most Windows computers this is not necessary, but on some computers it is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

You can enable virtual terminal processing using just standard library packages:

In `init_windows.go`

```golang
//go:build windows

package main

import (
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

func init() {
    stdout := syscall.Handle(os.Stdout.Fd())

    var originalMode uint32
    syscall.GetConsoleMode(stdout, &originalMode)
    originalMode |= 0x0004
    
    syscall.MustLoadDLL("kernel32").MustFindProc("SetConsoleMode").Call(uintptr(stdout), uintptr(originalMode))
}
```